# how to release memory in java

Tags: java

i create Object of class A. at that time java occupy memory for class A. but when i assign null in object of Class A then it can free memory of that object

```
class A{
    public long num = 28115733;

}
```

Comment: Damn everyone knows that ;) You can read a nice article http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/gcP.html

Answer (score 6):

If you assign Object of class A reference to null, then Object A is **eligible** for GC (it may not immediately release memory) .

When memory will be freed is upto JVM and garbage collector (GC) algorithms being used.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot be sure about that. When you assign `null` to an `object reference`, then the `object` pointed to by that reference is `eligible` for `Garbage Collection`.

But it is completely upto the `JVM` when it `releases` the `memory` occupied by that `object`.

May be when `JVM` sees that the `memory` is getting low, then it can `kick off` the `garbage collector` to free up some memory. But that is completely a background process. You don't have to worry about that.
Also, if you want to explicitly tell the `JVM` to recollect memory, then you can add a call to `System.gc()`. But again JVM will not immediately start the `Garbage Collection` process. That would be on `JVM` only.

Answer (score 0):

> when i assign null in object of Class A then it can free memory of that object

Yes, it can but it won't free memory until it has to.

Answer (score 0):

Memory in Java is reclaimed by the garbage collector (a process which looks for unreachable objects and returns their memory for use) You do not need to explicitly set an object to null for this to happen.